# How to properly setup credentials manually for Cloud Speech-to-Text API in python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, raspberry-pi, raspbian, google-cloud-speech

Ok, this is my first question in the site so I going to try to be clear.
I am trying to build a speech recognition application in the raspberry pi with python and the Cloud Speech-to-Text API. While trying to set the credentials for the application defining a variable in the Terminal (following the steps shown here: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python) I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/pythonPrograms/GoogleSpeech.py", line 15, in <module>
    client = speech.SpeechClient()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/gapic/speech_client.py", line 137, in __init__
    credentials=credentials,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/gapic/transports/speech_grpc_transport.py", line 63, in __init__
    credentials=credentials,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/gapic/transports/speech_grpc_transport.py", line 98, in create_channel
    scopes=cls._OAUTH_SCOPES,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 177, in create_channel
    credentials, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=scopes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 306, in default
    raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

As that didn't work, I tried to set the credentials manually inside the code. The problem is, I keep getting the same error (probably because I'm not doing it right). Here is my code right now:

```
import io
import os   

# Imports the Google Cloud client library

from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("/root/Downloads/key.json")
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"])

from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types

# Instantiates a client
client = speech.SpeechClient()

# The name of the audio file to transcribe
file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'resources',
    'audio.raw')

# Loads the audio into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()
    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=16000,
    language_code='en-US')

# Detects speech in the audio file
response = client.recognize(config, audio)

for result in response.results:
    print('Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
```

While searching for a solution I tried eliminating the part of the code that says:

```
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types
```

To what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/pythonPrograms/GoogleSpeech.py", line 12, in <module>
    client = speech.SpeechClient()
NameError: name 'speech' is not defined
```

Thus, I suppose the problem is within the way that I imported that, and not in the credential itself. It is important to add that I activated the API in my Google Cloud account project. 
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This post is over 2 years old but I bumped into the same problem (I wanted to explicitly set the credentials in the code for testing)

The only thing you need to do is to pass the credential as credential argument to SpeechClient as follows:

```
import io
import os   

# Imports the Google Cloud client library

from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("/path/to/key.json")
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"])

from google.cloud import speech

# Instantiates a client
client = speech.SpeechClient(credentials=credentials)
```

Alternatively, you could also use `from_service_account_file` method directly in SpeechClient:

```
from google.cloud import speech

# Instantiates a client
client = speech.SpeechClient.from_service_account_file("/path/to/key.json")
```

If your credentials set-up is OK any of the options should work without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly indicates that environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is not set.

The [ReadMe](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/cloud-client) file for the reference code mentions that you have to setup the authentication. Basically you need to create a service account, give the service account necessary permissions(= set a role, this depends on what do you want to do with the account), download the credentials json file and set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to point to your json file. Actual steps vary depending on your OS, whole process is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started).

Comment: Yes, I had already created the account, setup the authentication and got the credentials. I also set the environment variable. I explained this when I made my question, I don't understand where does your answer come from.

Comment: @Linye Look at the last line of the error that you posted. This gives you the error and the solution.

Comment: I know, "speech" is not defined because the speech api is not imported. That's why I am asking for help on how to import it when I am settingn the credentials inside the code.

Comment: @Linye what do you see when you run the export command? paste the output to the question

Answer (score 0):

I use os command to solve Google-Credential issue. set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable in Python code following.

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "path of your JSON credential file"
```

This will be worth for the issue.